# Sanitise string to remove slashes in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

When I run my script locally I can sanitise strings perfectly and remove slashes:

```bash
get_branch_name () {
  local branch_name="$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD)"
  echo $branch_name
}

feature_branch_name="$(get_branch_name)"
feature_branch_name_no_backslash=$(echo $feature_branch_name | sed 's/\//-/')
```

However on my remote Linux server `sed` does not work and I have not been able to make this work at all so far, using whichever combination of solutions I find on the web.

I want to replace slashes with dashes as it is used as a file name and slashes will create sub folders.

How can I achieve this with substitution or sed?

Comment: When you say "sed does not work": Is it not installed, or does it show some error?

Comment: Thanks - it does not have any effect unlike when I run it locally in my terminal - there is no error

Comment: If you change from `\/` to `[/]` does that address the problem? (Whether it would depends on _how_ you're passing the command to the remote machine, which you haven't shown us; but backslashes are generally fragile -- they're easily consumed, which is why they're not the best choice among forms of escaping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter expansion with from/to:

```
feature_branch_name_no_backslash=${feature_branch_name//\//-}
```

Comment: Thank you, this only replaces the first slash though. Can it replace every slash?

Comment: I've amended the answer